# How to change LaunchScreen image after already having set it?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ios10, launch

I want to change my LaunchScreen image. I have already set the image, but I decided to change it, and now, when I launch the app it's all black. How to set another image? I put images in assets.xcassets in 1x, 2x and 3x sizes.

Comment: Yeah i used lounchscreen.storyboard

Comment: No it is not working, in LaunchScreen.storyboard i put a UIImageView and i have set the image when i started building the app. Now i want to change that image, and When i set another image it displays a black screen When i run it.

Comment: Then the image view's `image` does not match the name of the image set in the asset catalog.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the image from attribute inspector as like I have done in this figure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1nJt.png)
clean and build again
cmd+shift+K and build and run it will work

Comment: I changed image this way, but it doesn't register it.

Comment: clean and build again